# Does use of COALESCE slows down the query performance

Tags: sql-server

I was just curious to know that the use of COALESCE slows down the query performance. I read it in an article that we should avoid using COALESE and instead of it, we should use case for this. Is it really true about COALESE that it hinders the query perfromance? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a link to that article?

Comment: Essentially - while it naturally cost performance - the question is "how much performance does it cost in relevance to your actual query" and whether or not it's the first place to try and optimize.

Comment: Hi Allan, I just wrote the information as an answer, could you please go through it and let me know if its really okay. I mean I am really confused with this Coalesce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m currently going through the procedures executed the most frequently and looking at the ones with a high average duration.  I am seeing a lot of cases where we are using optional parameters with a COALESCE in the WHERE clause, like this:
WHERE schedule.CustNum = COALESCE(@CustNum, Schedule.CustNum)

These procedures will be inherently slow to run.  When they’re compiled, the COALESCE throws off the compiler, and it ends up using a plan that scans the entire table.  As we’ve gotten bigger & bigger tables as our volumes has grown, this has become more of an issue, and in some cases we end up with a procedure that takes upwards of 10 seconds to run when it’d run almost instantly if an optional parameter was not used

Comment: The main reasons for that is the lack of index usage due to the "conditional where" and not coalesce as such. So that means Tomas' answer is the correct one in your situation. It's not coalesce that' slow, it the lack of index usage

Comment: Hi Yash. See above for an alternative method that may help in your situation

Answer (score 6):

I can't be sure about SQL Server. However I will give my experience of it in Oracle just in case there may be a correlation. It depends on the context that you are using it.
For example consider the case where you may have a predicate in your SQL statement that reads as follows:

```
SELECT UserId, FirstName, Surname,  DepartmentId
FROM Users
WHERE DepartmentId = COALESCE(pDepartmentId,DepartmentId)
```

The use of the COALESCE in this context (in Oracle at least - and yes, I realise this is a SQL Server question) would preclude the use of any index on the DepartmentId.

As I said, it depends on the context and although this is from an Oracle point of view I would suspect the same may apply to SQL Server.

**EDIT**

I have just seen your post on the context that you use it and it is exactly the same as the above.

What you could try in your case would be the following which is a neat trick I learned to avoid the problem - again - Oracle but could work for you.

```
SELECT UserId, FirstName, Surname,  DepartmentId
FROM Users
WHERE pDepartmentId IS NOT NULL AND DepartmentId = pDepartmentId

UNION ALL

SELECT UserId, FirstName, Surname,  DepartmentId
FROM Users
WHERE pDepartmentId IS NULL
```

Sorry for interloping on a SQL Server post but if this helps you it may be worth it.

**Final Edit**

As I commented below the CASE statement does indeed get around the issue. Therefore, no need for the over-complicated UNION hack (which incidently gives the same cost as the CASE). Unfortunately, I still need to use this in Oracle. Another win for the MSSQL case (no pun intended!!)

Comment: This is true and important for SQL Server as well, when using coalesce (and ISNULL etc) as a condition which involves indexing

Comment: This is correct, but cant this be achieved with using "CASE" as well?

Comment: I don't have SQL Server handy to do a test but if you can read your execution plans then that should tell you. In your test use the coalesce, then the case statement. Look at your execution plans and in particular look for full table scans (if custnum is highly selective which I guess it is then you would hope not for any full table scans)

Comment: Ok, I managed to do a test and the cost is comparable with use the CASE statement as with comparison directly against the column. Using a coalesce will use a "Clustered Index Scan" (2.82446 I/O Cost in my test) and using a CASE will use an "Index Seek" (0.003125 I/O Cost in my test) .

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE` could hurt your performance, but not compared to `CASE`, because it's actually just a `CASE` by another name.

`ISNULL` could lead to better perf in some cases. But be aware of other differences between them, mainly the return type.

Compare execution plans for these three queries:

```
use AdventureWorks2012;
go
select coalesce((select CustomerID from Sales.SalesOrderHeader where SalesOrderId = 10000), 0)
select isnull((select CustomerID from Sales.SalesOrderHeader where SalesOrderId = 10000), 0)
select case 
    when (select CustomerID from Sales.SalesOrderHeader where SalesOrderId = 10000) is null then 0
    else (select CustomerID from Sales.SalesOrderHeader where SalesOrderId = 10000)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, for SQL Server 2016+, COALESCE is a real dog performance-wise.  Especially after SQL 2016.  An example of our experience is a stored procedure we wrote that included a WHERE clause that contained 8 COALESCE statements; on a large data set (~300k rows) this stored procedure took nearly a minute to run.  When we reduced the number to 1 COALESCE statement, the same query ran in under a second.  That was the only change.

I understand this is anecdotal and honestly I couldn't tell you why it began performing so poorly, but that's what our experience has been.  Perhaps it's a database configuration issue.  If you're able to check with `IS NULL` in cases instead, it'll save you some trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a poor performing view with a COALESCE (in the SELECT clause) of 2 instances of a varchar(30) column from a small heap left joined twice. Harmless right?  I never would have believed that was the problem but after breaking it down, isolating and indexing for an hour I tried switching to a CASE statement out of desperation. The run duration dropped from 1:42 to 0:00. I still don't understand it. the execution plan indicated a hash match on a worktable. SS version is 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Who said that?

FYI :

1) It is ANSI standards ( vs isnull)

2) It provides more functionally since it it takes more than 1 params.

3) The fastest way would be : `if @s is null...`

4) does it REALLY hurts your performance ? I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

Like any function, `COALESCE` has it's place and it is part of the ANSI 92 SQL standard which means it is widely implemented across RDMBSs. You can, if you only require a test on one value, use `ISNULL`. Whilst some poeple will complain that this isn't in the SQL standard (which is true), lots of platforms implement it in one form or another.

Under the covers `COALESCE` actually equates to a `CASE` statement, although I'm not sure about `ISNULL`.

There's a pretty good write up and discussion [on this MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx). And yes, there **ARE** seom circumstances where there can be a performance hit, but they're pretty specific as detailed in that blog.

tl;dr - Horses for courses. If you need to find the first non-null in a series then `COALESCE` is for you otherwise `ISNULL` should suffice. As always, if you're worried about performance (and it's only in certain circumstances where you should be as far as `COALESCE` is concerned - see link for one example) then get friendly with execution plans and how to interpret them.